# In-painting using machine learning / AI techniques in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, plugin

Are there any recommended techniques for "inpainting" sections within a photoshop image using AI techniques such as Stable Diffusion or DALL-E?

I've found good examples of how to use Stable Diffusion [as a photoshop plugin for generation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdctF1uTLBo), and I've seen examples of people [in painting using other tools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N913hReVxMM), but no instructions on how to set this up within Photoshop itself.

Note: I'm *not* talking about using the built-in Content Aware fill or Neural Filters.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? PS doesn't support AI painting without the additional tools

Comment: I'm looking for a plugin that does.

Comment: The first video you posted has instructions for installing the plugin. You'd need the key for a specific API the plugin works with

Comment: (There are no free one-click-install alternatives at the moment)

Comment: I’ve installed that plugin but it doesn’t do in-painting. My question is about in painting.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe recently announced the beta of its AI product [Firefly](https://www.adobe.com/sensei/generative-ai/firefly.html) which supports inpainting.

Otherwise, you will find plug-ins made by third parties but they often necessitate other working parts such as Automatic1111. The most up-to-date one I know of as of the time of writing this response is https://github.com/AbdullahAlfaraj/Auto-Photoshop-StableDiffusion-Plugin which supports models and ControlNet among others. The document has installation instructions and a demo which I strongly recommend viewing. It is not an intuitive tool out of the box at all.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an interessant plugin for generated inpainting within Photoshop itself:
https://www.getalpaca.io/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/113423)

Comment: Hi Bertrand and welcome to GD.SE. Please review our [guidelines for spam](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

Comment: Hi, sorry but you're mistaken, I reread the question and my answer is relevant, the question was about "how to do inpainting" in photoshop, and I give the name of a tool that to do that in photoshop :-) - The user even adds "I'm looking for a plugin that does."